# Como obter via IN os registros encontrados e não encontrados

Tags: sql, oracle, algoritmo-de-busca

Tenho um comando simples

```
SELECT MATRICULA FROM ALUNOS WHERE ID_ALUNO IN (1,2,3,4,5,6)
```

Gostaria de saber como obter via SQL um resultado assim:

ID| ALUNO

1  | LUIZ

2  | MARIA

3  |

4  | JOÃO

5  | CARLOS

6  |

Ou seja, trazer os que ele achou, e os que não achou deixar em branco... tem como via SQL?

Estou usando Oracle 11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como os dados não existem deve-se recorrer a um "artifício"

```
SELECT MATRICULA , NOME FROM ALUNOS WHERE ID_ALUNO IN (1,2,3,4,5,6)
union
SELECT MATRICULA,NOME
FROM (SELECT ROWNUM MATRICULA, '' NOME FROM USER_OBJECTS WHERE ROWNUM < 7) VIRTUAL
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM ALUNOS WHERE ID_ALUNO = MATRICULA)
```

Um union trás os dados não existentes.
A user_objects é só uma tabela "fajuta" para gerar uma sequencia

Comment: Valeu pela ajuda cara o/ Assim funciona mesmo, mas como o meu objetivo final era atualizar uma planilha excel que já tinha todos os IDs, e eu só precisava ver quais estavam no sistema, eu acabei fazendo o select pra trazer todos e validei pelo excel mesmo huaehUEHiHEuheuheiuhaie, o importante é funcionar!!!